# Complex Column Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I'm trying to mount a column chart with this xml, my idea is make horizontalAxis with `<CategoryAxis categoryField="INICIO_CICLO"/>` and series like above, but have two bars (CUSTOMER) value C1 and C2 but the user can choose C1 or C2 or both. How can I mount this? Thanks for helping me.

```
<mx:ColumnSet type="stacked">
    <mx:series>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="CUSTOMER" displayName="Customer"/>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="VALIDACAO_CONTAS" displayName="Tempo Validação Contas"/>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="VALOR_FATURA" displayName="Tempo Valor Fatura"/>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="GERA_NF" displayName="Tempo Gera NF"/>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="GERA_FATURA" displayName="Tempo Gera Fatura"/>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="INICIO_CICLO" yField="ENVIO_VENDOR" displayName="Tempo Envio Vendor"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:ColumnSet>
```

XML:

```
<dados>
<dado>
<CUSTOMER>c2</CUSTOMER>
<INICIO_CICLO>17-MAY-12</INICIO_CICLO>
<VALIDACAO_CONTAS>201</VALIDACAO_CONTAS>
<VALOR_FATURA>117</VALOR_FATURA>
<GERA_NF>61</GERA_NF>
<GERA_FATURA>44</GERA_FATURA>
<ENVIO_VENDOR>220</ENVIO_VENDOR>
<TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>642</TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>
<QTD_CONTAS_BIP>1918</QTD_CONTAS_BIP>
<QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>531</QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>
<QTD_ERRO_BIP>0</QTD_ERRO_BIP>
<QTD_SKIP_BIP>11</QTD_SKIP_BIP>
<QTD_ERRO_EIF>0</QTD_ERRO_EIF>
<QTD_FAT_ZERADA>159</QTD_FAT_ZERADA>
<QTD_ENV_ABNC>3425</QTD_ENV_ABNC>
<QTD_CDR>34.3726</QTD_CDR>
<QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS>5583</QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS>
<QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>5220</QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>
</dado>
<dado>
<CUSTOMER>c1</CUSTOMER>
<INICIO_CICLO>17-MAY-12</INICIO_CICLO>
<VALIDACAO_CONTAS>199</VALIDACAO_CONTAS>
<VALOR_FATURA>212</VALOR_FATURA>
<GERA_NF>63</GERA_NF>
<GERA_FATURA>111</GERA_FATURA>
<ENVIO_VENDOR>58</ENVIO_VENDOR>
<TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>642</TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>
<QTD_CONTAS_BIP>2011</QTD_CONTAS_BIP>
<QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>629</QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>
<QTD_ERRO_BIP>2</QTD_ERRO_BIP>
<QTD_SKIP_BIP>53</QTD_SKIP_BIP>
<QTD_ERRO_EIF>0</QTD_ERRO_EIF>
<QTD_FAT_ZERADA>79</QTD_FAT_ZERADA>
<QTD_ENV_ABNC>3425</QTD_ENV_ABNC>
<QTD_CDR>68.14276</QTD_CDR>
<QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS>5016</QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS><QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>3723</QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>
</dado>
<dado>
<CUSTOMER>c1</CUSTOMER>
<INICIO_CICLO>17-JUN-12</INICIO_CICLO>
<VALIDACAO_CONTAS>399</VALIDACAO_CONTAS>
<VALOR_FATURA>141</VALOR_FATURA>
<GERA_NF>48</GERA_NF>
<GERA_FATURA>22</GERA_FATURA>
<ENVIO_VENDOR>5</ENVIO_VENDOR>
<TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>614</TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>
<QTD_CONTAS_BIP>2057</QTD_CONTAS_BIP>
<QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>664</QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>
<QTD_ERRO_BIP>4</QTD_ERRO_BIP>
<QTD_SKIP_BIP>74</QTD_SKIP_BIP>
<QTD_ERRO_EIF>0</QTD_ERRO_EIF>
<QTD_FAT_ZERADA>82</QTD_FAT_ZERADA>
<QTD_ENV_ABNC>3480</QTD_ENV_ABNC>
<QTD_CDR>67.2716</QTD_CDR>
<QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS>5153</QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS><QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>3854</QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>
</dado>
<dado>
<CUSTOMER>c2</CUSTOMER>
<INICIO_CICLO>17-JUN-12</INICIO_CICLO>
<VALIDACAO_CONTAS>213</VALIDACAO_CONTAS>
<VALOR_FATURA>92</VALOR_FATURA>
<GERA_NF>28</GERA_NF>
<GERA_FATURA>46</GERA_FATURA>
<ENVIO_VENDOR>235</ENVIO_VENDOR>
<TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>614</TEMPO_TOTAL_CICLO>
<QTD_CONTAS_BIP>2122</QTD_CONTAS_BIP>
<QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>553</QTD_CONTAS_NOBILL>
<QTD_ERRO_BIP>0</QTD_ERRO_BIP>
<QTD_SKIP_BIP>8</QTD_SKIP_BIP>
<QTD_ERRO_EIF>0</QTD_ERRO_EIF>
<QTD_FAT_ZERADA>162</QTD_FAT_ZERADA>
<QTD_ENV_ABNC>3480</QTD_ENV_ABNC>
<QTD_CDR>42.55141</QTD_CDR>
<QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS>5767</QTD_TOTAL_LEVANTADAS><QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>5131</QTD_N_INSTANCIA_ATIVA>
</dado>
</dados>
```

Comment: I edited your post to break up the code, making it readable. You don't want to use the ` tags for blocks of codes. Write in or paste the code, and then highlight it and press the {} button in the edit window. That'll convert it into a code block.

Comment: Tks JasonMc92 I'll do this in the next time.

Comment: (If the edit isn't showing up, it'll as soon as it is peer reviewed. I'm working my way up to full edit permissions.)